# how to pass parameter to WebService in Spring DSL

Tags: web-services, spring, dsl

I am new to apache Camel. I am trying to invoke a simple calculator WebService which I have created netbeans using Metro JAXWS . The Calculator has one webmethod with following signature:

```
int add int a, int b
```

Now, my goal is to invoke this webservice using Apache camel, cxf component. After reading multiple tutorials and examples, I completed following steps:

1) Used wsdl2java tool to generate WebService stub in the project. 
2) Defined CXFEndpoint in camel-cxf.xml.

```
   <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="calEndPoint"`
       address="http://localhost:8080/Calculator/Calculator"
       serviceClass="com.test.calculatorbeanws.Calculator"
       wsdlURL="wsdl/calculator.wsdl"/>
```

3) Now, I am trying to create a route in camel-context.xml to call this web-service. It should look something like this.

```
     <camel:route>
        <camel:from ....." />
        <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:calEndPoint"/>            
        <camel:to uri="file:someoutputfile"/>            
     </camel:route>
```

So, the problem is defining this route. How can I pass parameters a and b to calEndPoint, and how can I write the output to some output file or display it on console using Spring DSL.

Hopefully, I have explained the problems in detail. If anybody has any suggestion, please let me know.

Thanks